# Haskell pattern matching implicit type

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm new to Haskell, and i'm trying to make something with pattern matching. I don't even know if it's possible in that way.
I have a data Fml :

```hs
    data Fml a = And (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | NAnd (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | Or (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | NOr (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | XOr (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | XNOr (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | Imply (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | Equiv (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | Not (Fml a)
    | Final (Var.Var a)
    deriving (Show)
```

Var is just a value (example : 1)
I'm trying to make an easy function to merge all the Var in one Array. I've done this :

```hs
getVar :: (Eq a) => Fml a -> [Fml a]
getVar (And p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (NAnd p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (Or p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (NOr p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (XOr p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (XNOr p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (Imply p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (Equiv p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (Not p) = getVar p
getVar x = [x]
```

But i'm not satisfied because 8 of thoose cases are doing the same thing.
I would like to know if it's possible to do something like this

```hs
getVar (_ p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
```

Comment: The last case should be `getVar (Final x) = [x]` right? Also this isn't possible unless you want to write [Template Haskell](https://markkarpov.com/tutorial/th.html) code.

Comment: getVar x = [x] is working fine because i want to return an [Fml]
Okay ! Thanks :)

Comment: @NicolasFAU: but that looks "odd" since your function hints you are returning *variables*, and here you are returning *formulas*. *formulas* all with the same data constructor, but that is not known by the type constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a type for the operator:

```
data Op2 = And | NAnd | Or | NOr | Xor | XNor | Imply | Equiv
```

and then define a data constructor that takes an operator and two parameters:

```
data Fml a
    = Fml2 Op2 (Fml a) (Fml a)
    | Not (Fml a)
    | Final (Var.Var a)
    deriving (Show)
```

Then your function thus looks like:

```
getVar :: Eq a => Fml a -> [Var.Var a]
getVar (Fml2 _ p q) = getVar p ++ getVar q
getVar (Not p) = getVar p
getVar (Final v) = [v]
```

I think the output type should be a list of `Var.Var`s, and not a `Fml a`, since your function hints that it is looking for a list of variables.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot.
For the return of the function, I poorly expressed myself. I need Fml and not Var

Comment: @NicolasFAU: Still, it’s advisable to make the result type of `getVar` be `[Var a]`, since it’s more precise. Then if you want to make an `Fml` from that, you can simply `map Final` over it, but you won’t need spurious pattern matches like `case x of { Final v -> {- do something with var -}; _ -> error "should not happen" }` when you *know* that you have a variable.